# Ionic 4: How to set navigation direction (backward/forward) using routerLink?

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular7, direction, ionic4, routerlink

Ionic 4 now uses Angular router. Altough it still has its own NavControler, which helps to simulate push / pop navigation style though the navigateBackward and navigateForward methods.

So that ion-back-button is shown it is necessary to use navigateForward and navigateBackward, I think.

In my application I prefer to use routerLinks to navigate (so that the user can open the page in another tab) instead of navController.

But with routerLinks the ion-back-button does not appears. There must be an way to make routerLinks act like push/pop navigation.

How could I simulate an event like navigateForward and navigateBackward using routerLinks?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the attribute routerDirection on your view element.
For example

```
  <ion-button [routerLink]="['/details']" routerDirection="forward" >
    Go forward
  </ion-button>
```

For a full detailed description of how to manage navigation in Ionic 4 including routerLink you should read [Josh's very detailed blog post](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-angular-routing-with-ionic-4/)

Comment: Kindly also tell the value of routerDirection for backward animation

Comment: `<ion-button href="/products" routerDirection="backward">`

Comment: For more details again Josh is here for you! https://www.joshmorony.com/converting-ionic-3-push-pop-navigation-to-angular-routing-in-ionic-4/

Comment: It's `routerDirection="back"` not "backward" FYI.

Comment: How to do this directly in typescript?

Answer (score 2):

Moving from Ionic 3 to Ionic 4 with navigating has changed up quite a bit, but the changes aren't too bad. The Ionic Docs recommend to switch to Angular Routing instead of the traditional Ionic pop and push. There are a couple of way to route your pages, but I think the easiest to understand is using the `navigateForward()` and `navigateBack()` functions in the .ts file.

Ex.

```js
navigateForward(){
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/route of the page you want to navigate to');
  }
```

```html
<ion-button large block (click)="navigateForward()">
      Navigate Forward
</ion-button>
```

Of course navigating forward and backward has to do with the structure of how your app is build from the stack.

The `app-routing.module.ts` file will automatically create the routes for your generated pages, but you can manually change the routes there as well as set a root page.

A good reference to routing tutorials [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-angular-routing-with-ionic-4/). Also shows different ways to navigate using routes throughout your app.

Comment: Ionic recommends not using NavController anymore. How can this be done only using router?

Comment: @Otziii it looks like Ionic decided to completely use angular routing now. their documentation here:https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/navigation can help or if not look for Angular routing for help.

Comment: @Otziii Did you find any solution to do this with router ? StephenRomero Bro I couldn't find any routerdirection in the link you uploaded

Comment: @NischayaSharma Sorry, I don't remember.

Comment: @NischayaSharma You have to use 100% Angular routing now. This should still be feasible with Angular though.

Comment: @StephenRomero I tried with angular routing, but I still can't use any feature like router direction as using Nav Ctrl is not recommended. So all my pages are going forward only by default.

Comment: Does anyone know how this would be done via this.router.navigate()?

Answer (score 2):

use `routerDirection="back"`
this will change the page transition like going back with your `routerLink`

#transition #ionic